# microsoft excel - how to fit image inside shape?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

i have typed some image locations in some cells and hyperlinked them. when i click this cells, a macro will be executed and fills a rectangle shape with pictures specified in those cells. this is the macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Row = ActiveCell.Row
col = ActiveCell.Column

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 38")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, col).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

it works but the picture is stretched. i want the picture to be fitted inside my shape. in excel , as you might know , after filling a shape with picture,there is a fit button under crop option. when you click it, it fits the image inside the picture box and maintains the size of shape. i want to do the exact thing only in VBA.

Comment: Set the dimensions to match? With height, width etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shape properties of  .`PictureWidth , .PictureHeight , .PictureOffsetX =  .PictureOffsetY.`

Code example:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AddPicAndAdjust()

    Dim shp As ShapeRange
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1"))
    With shp.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture "C:\Users\User\Pictures\MyNicePic.png" '<== Add pic
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .RotateWithObject = msoTrue
    End With

    'Positioning within fill
    With shp.PictureFormat.Crop
        .PictureWidth = 231
        .PictureHeight = 134
        .PictureOffsetX = 50
        .PictureOffsetY = 28
    End With

    With shp
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .IncrementLeft 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: that's not what i want. let me explain more. when you fill a shape with picture, there are other options in user interface u can set.in crop you can select fit and under fill option you have offset left, offset right, offset top and offset bottom. i have to know the VBA correspondence to this options.

Comment: Example now given for that.